# Need background image of empty div to display in proper ratio across all screen sizes

Tags: css, wordpress, background, responsive-design, background-size

I have a section that will initially only contain a play button which will show a video gallery once clicked. This section has to contain an image as well which I decided to include as the `background` to the section itself (`#intro`).

The problem was that since there wasn't anything in the section besides a play button, the background wasn't being stretched enough vertically to show the entire background image. I remedied this by including a `padding-bottom` of 57.201%. That fixed it initially but I also had to position the play button in the center and once I tried doing that with margins and paddings, it became a mess with huge gaps showing at the bottom of the image after resizing the browser due to the percentage I set for `padding-bottom`.

So, I need this thing to be responsive and I would ideally like to set some breakpoints as well to cater to users on devices with smaller screens.

Here is a screenshot to give a better idea. When the play button in the center is clicked, a video gallery (`#feat-video`) is supposed to pop up within the white outlined rectangle.

[image]

HTML

```
<section id="intro">
    <div class="section-wrap">
        <a class="video-toggle" href="#">Toggle</a>
        <div id="feat-video" style="display:none">
            (video gallery here)
        </div>
    </div><!-- .section-wrap -->
</section>
```

CSS

```
#intro {
    background: url("img/intro-banner.jpg") no-repeat center top $color__brand-blue;
    background-size: cover;
    padding-bottom: 57.201%;

    #feat-video {
        padding-top: 224px;
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try to set height and width of #intro to 100% and remove the padding-bottom?

Comment: @Doodlebunch Yes, but the height didn't change because the only content in that section is a play button. If only there was a way to stretch an empty div to match its background image.

Comment: Try to set width and height to 100vw and 100vh. It's viewport-width and viewport-height. http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units compability.

Comment: Can't you just give the section with the white oultline no background and use the image as the body background?

Comment: @Doodlebunch Just tried that (thank you, didn't know that existed), but is there a way to set a max-width on the image? When I test the site on devices wider than 1600px (the width of the image), it starts stretching to fit the viewport.

Comment: Why not set max-width: 1600px to the element? Then add margin: 0 auto; and it should be centered horizontally.

Answer (score 0):

I know you didn't ask for a javascript/jQuery solution, but you could simply use this for a perfectly fitted background:

```
function viewport() {
    var e = window, a = 'inner';
    if (!('innerWidth' in window )) {
        a = 'client';
        e = document.documentElement || document.body;
    }
    return { width : e[ a+'Width' ] , height : e[ a+'Height' ] };
}

$('#intro').css('min-height', viewport().height);
```

**Update**

If you want to maintain the effect on resize (which normally you don't need, on page load should be sufficient), you have to add the respective call in jQuery. Here is a fiddle I created for you to demonstrate it: http://jsfiddle.net/zgzt8dom/3/

Comment: Thank you. I'm open to using JavaScript. Is there any way to set a max-width on the image so it doesn't stretch horizontally past 1600px?

Comment: Just use a `media-query` and replace the `background-size` declaration with your desired max-width above 1600px..

Comment: I can't seem to get this to work. Do I keep my original CSS? I removed `background-size: cover`, `padding-bottom: 57.201%` and added in your function. However, when my browser is maximized at 1600 width, the height of the div displays shorter than the image (1600x915px is the size of the image but the image displays as 1583x802px) and when I resize the browser to test for responsiveness, the image doesn't resize. I suppose the 1583px width is due to the scroll bar on the browser and maybe that's affecting the height as well? Anyway to get around that?

Comment: I switched out the code and now there is empty space below the image which just shows the background color of the div. Also, when I resize the browser, the image still doesn't adapt proportionally to the new browser size. It just stays the same size. I checked out your fiddle and it's not resizing the width there either. Sorry if I'm not explaining things clearly. I'm just looking to have the image reduce in size proportionally as the browser width gets reduced.

Comment: Try adding `overflow: hidden;` to `#intro`.

Comment: I added that but nothing has changed.

Comment: Please create a fiddle with your code, I can't help you anymore without it.